# Rails request_parameters include controller infos, How to only get POST data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request

I send a application/json post request:

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/flowers/growth' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"type": 1}'
```

then I use **request.request_parameters**, the output is:

```
{"type"=>1, "flower"=>{}}
```

why the "flower"=>{} will be auto added?

How can I only get the POST data, not include the controller infos

Answer (score 3):

Okay, after struggling on this exact issue for hours myself, and digging through the call stack, I found the answer.

First off, the reason I wanted to solve this problem was because I wanted to give feedback to the sender if an invalid element was used, rather than just accept the valid values and ignore the others.  For this reason, the other solutions on this page wouldn't work for me.

So the nub of the issue is this thing called `ActionController::ParamsWrapper`, which is found in `actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb`.  This code wraps the request parameters for your controller in your controller's name to *make access easier*.  However, if you've got a dedicated api JSON interface, this just makes life worse.

To tell this eager "helper" to bugger off, add the following line to your controller:

`wrap_parameters format: []`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice` to get just the parameters you're looking for:

```
request.request_parameters.slice(:type) #=> { 'type' => 1 }
```

Also you can use `params` as a shorthand for `request.request_parameters`. `params` has a few additional pieces of information though.

Comment: thx. I know params is a shorthand from request.request_parameters. I means I want to get only POST data, not include the controller infos. Now my solution is: post = request.request_parameters, post.delete('flower'), and the post is I looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Dude, like, why aren't you using the `params` hash?

```
params[:type]
```

Comment: the params will include controller info, action info. I means how to get POST data such like PHP $_POST, I want to get all POST data by only one time. So I don't use params[:type]

Comment: Change the format of your form elements. Instead of `<input name="type" value="1" />` use `<input name="thing[type]" value="1" />` and `<input name="thing[other_attr]" value="foo" />`. This will allow you to use `params[:thing]`. Spend more time educating yourself about Rails form parameters.

Answer (score -1):

There are many cases where using `params.slice` or similar isn't feasible (you may not know what parameters will be passed in) and you need to get only the POST parameters. In such a case, you can use `request.POST` within your controller.

Comment: request.request_parameters is just an alias to request.POST.  By the time your controller gets called, the ParamWrapper has already gone to work and added that extra element.